# How to perform labelling in the 3D extracted features in classification?

Tags: matlab, matrix, label, libsvm

I extracted the features from many images in 3D.
So the form of the extracted features (for example):

```
 Image 1 --> 10 x 12 x 30
 Image 2 --> 15 x 10 x 30
 Image 3 --> 13 x 12 x 30
 Image 4 --> 14 x 19 x 30
 .
 .
 So on
```

In which, the first and second dimension are always changing, but the third dimension is still same (the dimension of the feature).

To do classification, I need to label each extracted features from each image with a label.
And to make it easy, I have to keep that features (from each image) in a row.

So I reshape the features into

```
  feat_reshape= reshape(feature,[size(feature,1)*size(feature,2) size(feature,3)]);
```

In this case, I'll have 2D features matrix.
But still, I need it in 1D.

I already tried using "**imhist**" and keep each feature of each image in each row in a matrix. But still not give a good result. May be because there are many 0 value.

Then I tried to concatenate each column of each features (of each image), so become 1 row. But the problem for this is the different size of column in the concatenate matrix (element in each row).

For example :

```
  Image 1 --> 10 x 12 x 30 = 3600 elements
  Image 2 --> 15 x 10 x 30 = 4500 elements
```

Any suggestion,, how I can store my 3D extracted features and then label it to be used in LibSVM MATLAB??

Answer (score 0):

You will need some method to aggregate or pool your dense features per image, if your label is to be assigned to each image. Simple histogram is one approach. Alternatives are

- Just resize the original 3D image to fit into the fixed size, and compute features.
- [bag-of-words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model): First cluster per-pixel features and represent every pixel by its corresponding cluster index (visual words). Then summarize image by histogram.
- spatial-pyramid: Instead of histogram over the entire image, split the image into grids with different resolution (1x1, 2x2, etc), summarize features in each cell by histogram (or other pooling), and concatenate all of them. Pooling is a simple statistic, like min, max, mean, etc.

If none works well, suspect your feature design. Also try to find the best training parameter of SVM by cross validation (Check LibSVM documentation).

Comment: I perform HOG descriptor to extract the features. But as I mention before, the size of extracted features from each image is different M X N X 32 (only this 32 are same for every images)

Comment: Aggregation is to handle different image size, which in turn gives different M and N for each image.